# Добавить все файлы и подкаталоги в TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

Есть код:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Scan("folder");
    Console.ReadKey();
}

static void Scan(string path)
{
    foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(path))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(f);
    }
    foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(path))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(d);
        Scan(d);
    }
}
```

Вывод:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И вопрос: как это все добавить в TreeView, который в WPF, чтоб выглядело примерно на картинке? Типа обозреватель файлов

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Рекурсивное чтение каталога и добавление результата в Tree View](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/838033/%d0%a0%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b0-%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b2-tree-view)

Comment: Не совсем дубликат

Comment: И в чем отличия? Задача та жа, вопрос тот же, код и скрины теже. Отличие только в том, что тут "чуть чище" и побольше информаци, а так - одно и тоже..

Comment: Да и ответил я вам там на все... Если бы вы смотрели все, то увидели бы, что там идет цикл в цикле (поиск всех директорий и в каждой директории поиск всех файлов), а у вас идет два разрозненных цикла. Также и вывод, подробнейшая инструкция того, как грамотно в WPF реализовать TreeView, остается только заполнить. А вы заместо того, что бы спросить там, дополнить тот вопрос необходимым - создали новый вопрос, дубликат. Зачем?

Comment: Решил разделить, если нужно, тот вопрос удалю

Comment: Разделять нужно, если вопрос другой, а у вас тот же, с совершенно теми же данными. Вы так и не ответили, чем он отличается от того...

Comment: Упрощенно условие, побольше описание. Не понимаю, зачем докапываться то? Нельзя просто помочь?

Comment: Это НЕ докапываться, вы легко могли подредактировать старый вопрос, нажав кнопку "редактировать". Сейчас вот сравниваю удалённый вопрос - там уже готовый ответ был в комментариях, который теперь @EvgeniyZ не виден. Если вы думаете, что до вас докапываются - то подумайте о том, что другим кажется, что вы ни во что не ставите чужой труд и ещё не хотите свой вложить в оформление вопроса. И после этого просить "просто помочь"? Хм.

Comment: Ладно, я ошибся. Все же, мне тот ответ не очень помог, ибо не очень понятно для меня

Comment: Ну а что вам было не понятно? Я вам четко дал ссылку, в ней готовый вариант прохода по папкам и поиска файлов (бери да пользуйся), посмотреть лень уже было? Если бы вы посмотрели, то заметили, что там идет цикл в цикле, то есть мы берем папку, в ней ищем все файлы, вызываем заново этот метод, который ищет по кругу опять все файлы в папке и так до бесконечности, пока не дойдем до конца. А что видим у вас в коде? Два цикла, вывод всех папок и вывод всех файлов и они не как не связаны. А что касается TreeView, ну уж извините, подробней я писать не умею, в том ответе было **все** разжевано...

Comment: Поиск по папкам и так хорошо работает. Зачем лишние то?

Comment: Ну тогда вопрос в чем? Да и где ваши попытки?

Comment: Мне нужно добавить это все в Tree View, ну как на втором скрине. Проблема в том, что не знаю как реализовать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, для того, чтобы отобразить данные в TreeView, их нужно правильно приготовить. Элемент должен быть *иерархическим*, т.е. он должен иметь внутри себя ссылку на список дочерних элементов *такого же типа*. Не мудрствуя лукаво, я написал такой простейший класс:

```
class FileSystemEntry
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public IEnumerable<FileSystemEntry> Children { get; }
    public FileSystemEntry(string name, params FileSystemEntry[] children)
    {
        Name = name;
        Children = children;
    }
}
```

Я не стал заморачиваться, этот класс будет использоваться у меня и для файлов и для папок. Для файла достаточно передать один параметр-имя в конструктор, для папки дополнительно передаем массив дочерних элементов.

Теперь нам надо завести коллекцию корневых элементов (элементов верхнего уровня):

```
public IEnumerable<FileSystemEntry> FileSystemEntries { get; }
```

и как-то ее заполнить.

Метод для сканирования из вопроса нам не подходит, т. к. он выводит всё в консоль, но принцип, в нем использованный – то что нужно. Я переписываю так:

```
IEnumerable<FileSystemEntry> Scan(string path)
{
    // Папки будут идти в начале
    foreach (var dir in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(path))
        yield return new FileSystemEntry(Path.GetFileName(dir), Scan(dir).ToArray());
    // Файлы потом
    foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(path))
        yield return new FileSystemEntry(Path.GetFileName(file));
}
```

Остается только вызвать этот метод с каким-то параметром:

```
var path = @"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio";
FileSystemEntries = Scan(path).ToArray();
```

Коллекция заполнена, надо только привязать ее в GUI:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding FileSystemEntries}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
            <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Name}"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

Должно получиться что-то вроде:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А Вы бы не могли выложить исходник?

Comment: Исходника нет, я их не храню. Весь код в ответе, вам остаётся только установить DataContext, либо просто установить ItemsSource из кода

Comment: Просто не понимаю, куда строку public IEnumerable<FileSystemEntry> FileSystemEntries { get; }, в основной класс или в FileSystemEntry?

Comment: Если у вас MVVM-шаблон, то в VM. Вы же для начало можете положить прямо в MainWindow.cs. Там же в конструкторе (после `InitializeComponents()`) вставляете код для заполнения, потом `myTreeView.ItemsSource = FileSystemEntries;`

Comment: Спасибо, все работает