# C#. Получить выбранное значение и всех его "родителей" в TreeView WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

Как получить выбранное значение и всех его "родителей" в TreeView, которое в WPF?

Код в ответе tym32167 не работает. Возможно это из-за того что добавляю коллекцию TreeView?

 
Код: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/838339/270567

Comment: `myTreeView.SelectedValue`? `myTreeView.SelectedValue.Parent`?

Comment: Не то, и не то.

Comment: И там у вас ни `SelectedItem` нету, ни `SelectedNode`, ни `SelectedЧтонить`?

Comment: Есть `SelectedItem`, `SelectedValue` и `SelectedValuePath`, но ни в одном нет `Parent`

Comment: наличие `Parent` зависит от типа вашего узла, что вы туда вставляете.

Comment: Добавьте в класс `FileSystemEntry` свойство `public FileSystemEntry Parent { get; }` и всё, запись знает своего родителя.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот простецкое окошко

```
class W : Window
{
    public W()
    {
        var tv = new TreeView();

        var root = new TreeViewItem() { Header = "root" };
        var child = new TreeViewItem(){Header = "child"};

        root.Items.Add(child);      
        tv.Items.Add(root);     
        this.Content = tv;

        tv.MouseDoubleClick += (sender, args) => {      
            var selected = tv.SelectedItem as TreeViewItem;
            if (selected != null)
            {
                var parent = selected.Parent as TreeViewItem;
                if (parent != null)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show($"My parent is {parent.Header}");
                }
            }       
        };
    }
}
```

при двойном клике по дереву, логика смотрит выбранный узел и показывает текст его парента, если этот парент есть.

[image: parent]

**UPD**

Как посоветовали в комментах, надо добавить свойство родителя в ваш объект данных

```
class FileSystemEntry
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public IEnumerable<FileSystemEntry> Children { get; }
    public FileSystemEntry Parent{get;private set;}

    public FileSystemEntry(string name, params FileSystemEntry[] children)
    {
        Name = name;        
        Children = children;

        foreach(var c in Children)
            c.Parent = this;
    }
}
```

И все заработает.

**UPD2**

Полный код примера с вашим классом в качестве элемента. 
Разметка

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp2"
        mc:Ignorable="d" 
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding FileSystemEntries}" MouseDoubleClick="Control_OnMouseDoubleClick">
            <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Name}"/>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        </TreeView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Код

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;


namespace WpfApp2
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            FileSystemEntries = Scan(@"D:\temp\folder1");
            this.DataContext = this;
        }

        public IEnumerable<FileSystemEntry> FileSystemEntries { get; set; }

        IEnumerable<FileSystemEntry> Scan(string path)
        {
            // Папки будут идти в начале
            foreach (var dir in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(path))
                yield return new FileSystemEntry(Path.GetFileName(dir), Scan(dir).ToArray());
            // Файлы потом
            foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(path))
                yield return new FileSystemEntry(Path.GetFileName(file));
        }


        public class FileSystemEntry
        {
            public string Name { get; }
            public IEnumerable<FileSystemEntry> Children { get; }
            public FileSystemEntry Parent { get; private set; }

            public FileSystemEntry(string name, params FileSystemEntry[] children)
            {
                Name = name;
                Children = children;

                foreach (var c in Children)
                    c.Parent = this;
            }
        }

        private void Control_OnMouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (sender is TreeView tv)
            {
                var selected = tv.SelectedItem as FileSystemEntry;
                var parent = selected?.Parent;
                if (parent != null)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show($"My parent is {parent.Name}");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не знаю почему, но в `selected` у меня `null`, хотя я выбираю значение, и имя TreeView верно указал

Comment: Может быть, это из-за того что я добавляю коллекцию в TreeView?

Comment: Так вы никакого кода не привели. Откуда ж нам знать, что вы делаете так :)

Comment: Добавил код в вопрос

Comment: @deadmoz5er добавляйте код в ответ, а не ссылки. И смотрите обновление в моем ответе.

Comment: Не работает. Все еще null

Comment: Попробовал поменять там где `as TreeViewItem` на `as FileSystemEntry`, но выводит: `WPFApp.FileSystemEntry`

Comment: @deadmoz5er смотрите апдейт, там есть все, что вам нужно

Comment: Спасибо, код рабочий. Но это не совсем решает мою проблему, ибо мне нужно получить всех "родителей" выбранного значения

Comment: Решил проблему.

Answer (score 0):

**UPD3**

```
 var selected = FileList.SelectedItem as FileSystemEntry;
 var list = new List<string>();
 while (selected != null)
 {
     var parent = selected?.Parent as FileSystemEntry;
     selected = parent;
     if (parent != null)
         list.Add(parent.Name);
 }
 foreach (var m in list)
     MessageBox.Show(m);
```