# TreeView Parent WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

У меня есть выбранный элемент типа Item с TreeView. Как мне достучатся к родительскому объекту, чтобы удалить выбранный элемент из его коллекции Childs?
Item:

```
    public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public DateTime timeCreate = DateTime.Now;

    public ObservableCollection<Item> Childs { get; set; }
}
```

Наглядное изображение:

[image]

Comment: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: если вы привяжете команду удаления к узлу дерева, то есть у вас будет ссылка на узел, что надо удалить и ссылка на корень дерева, то обычный обход дерева в ширину или глубину поможет найти родителя и разобраться с удалением.

Comment: Не как дубликат, но как референс [тык](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/839542/179763) - там не самая классная реализация, по сути вам надо иметь отдельную VM и биндить её на UI, там же я просто окно использовал как VM