# Не работает шаблон TreeViewItem

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, wpf-шаблоны

Я пытаюсь кастомизировать элемент TreeView с помощью шаблонов. В дереве будет 2 уровня узлов (родитель и дочерний). Для каждого из них есть по шаблону:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="TreeViewItem" x:Key="ParentNodeTemplate">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">                    
                <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Header}" Margin="5,5,5,5"/>
                <Button Content="Обновить" Margin="5,5,5,5"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </ControlTemplate>
```

для родителя и

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="TreeViewItem" x:Key="ChildNodeTemplate">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Header}"/>
            </StackPanel>
</ControlTemplate>
```

для дочерних элементов. Шаблоны совсем простенькие исключительно для проверки работоспособности подхода. 
Само дерево в разметке выглядит просто:

```
<TreeView x:Name="tree"/>
```

Заполнение дерева происходит в коде таким образом:

```
foreach(var project in Service.MonitoredProjects)
{
    TreeViewItem parentItem = new TreeViewItem()
    {
        Header=project.Name,
        Template = (ControlTemplate)this.FindResource("ParentNodeTemplate"),
    };

    foreach (var mainfile in project.MainFileList)
    {
        TreeViewItem childItem = new TreeViewItem()
        {
            Header=mainfile.Name,
            Template = (ControlTemplate)this.FindResource("ChildNodeTemplate")
       };
        (parentItem.Items[0] as TreeViewItem).Items.Add(childItem);
    }                
    tree.Items.Add(parentItem);               
}
```

После всех этих манипуляций я получаю на выходе родительские элементы без возможности развернуть их. Хотя пошаговая проверка показала, что узлы-родители содержат в себе дочерние узлы. И вопрос мой в том, что я делаю не так и почему я не могу развернуть узлы?

Comment: Подозреваю, что родительский элемент должен содержать в себе `ItemsPresenter` для отображения дочерних: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/treeview-styles-and-templates (обратите внимание на `<ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsHost"` в шаблоне). Почему вы пошли таким путем, а не через `DataTemplate`?

Comment: С добавление `ItemPresenter` появился контент, он по прежнему не сворачивается, но уже по крайней мере есть и в принципе в статье описан механизм его скрытия/раскрытия. А насчет `DataTemplate`, я пошел таким путем потому, что свойство `TreeViewitem.Template` имеет тип `ControlTemplate`.

Comment: Для сворачивания там есть `<ToggleButton x:Name="Expander"` :) Про DataTemplate я имею ввиду переопределить только `TreeView.ItemTemplate`, весь же шаблон `TreeViewItem` править незачем, пусть его общая структура будет стандартной, будет меняться содержимое только этого элемента: `<ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_Header"`. Простой пример здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/838339/218063

Comment: А если необходимы различные шаблоны для различных уровней списка, то в ресурсах необходимо определять несколько `HierarchicalDataTemplate`?

Comment: Да, можно объявить несколько `HierarchicalDataTemplate` (или простых `DataTemplate`, например, для дочерних элементов, которые не имеют вложенных) и указать им `DataType`, после этого, WPF будет выбирать правильный шаблон *самостоятельно* в зависимости от типа привязанного элемента.

Comment: Тут возник вопрос, а в каком месте их разместить? В ресурсах окна? просто пытаюсь создать несколько различных шаблонов, назначая им свойство `DataType`, но получается ерунда. Работает только вариант с заданием свойства `TreeView.ItemTemplate` непосредственно в описании элемента. А при этом у родителей и у дочерних элементов шаблоны идентичны.

Comment: А вы `x:Key` не задайте, тогда они будут подхватываться автоматически. У вас данные, которые вы привязываете имеют разный тип?

Comment: `x:Key` я не задавал. У меня описано 2 класса, условно `Class1` и `Class2`, содержащие в себе несколько строковых полей. `Class1` содержит в себе свойство типа `List<Class2>`. Именно такую структуру я и хочу вывести.

Comment: В таком случае проблем не вижу, должно всё сработать, если вы используете привязки

Comment: @АндрейNOP, спасибо за помощь! Шаблон работает на полную, правда сейчас появился один вопрос. А как можно в случае с иерархическим шаблоном ловить событие `TreeViewItem.Expanded`?

Comment: В стиле `TreeView.ItemContainerStyle`, примерно как здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/826727/218063 Либо также добавляете привязку к `Property="IsExpanded"`, либо пишете `EventSetter` c `Event="Expanded"`

Comment: Как решите задачу — напишите здесь подробный ответ ("для потомков") чтобы топик не висел открытым

Answer (score 2):

Итак, с помощью @Андрей NOP я решил свою проблему.
По итогу получилось следующее:
Шаблон родителя:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MonitoredProject}" ItemsSource="{Binding MainFileList}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image MaxHeight="30" MaxWidth="30" Source="Images\folder_closed.png" ContextMenu="{StaticResource parentNodeMenu}"/>
        <Label Content="{Binding Name}" Margin="5,5,5,5" Foreground="{Binding Match, Converter={local:Converter}}" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="16" ContextMenu="{StaticResource parentNodeMenu}"/>
        <Button Content="Править" Margin="5,5,5,5" Click="EditProject_Clck" Tag="{Binding Name}"/>                               
    </StackPanel>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Шаблон дочернего элемента:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MonitoredFile}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image MaxHeight="35" MaxWidth="35" Source="{Binding SourceAdress, Converter={local:ImageConverter}}" ContextMenu="{StaticResource childNodeMenu}"/>
        <Label Content="{Binding Name}" Margin="5,5,5,5" Foreground="{Binding Match, Converter={local:Converter}}" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="14" ContextMenu="{StaticResource childNodeMenu}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Сам контрол:

```
<TreeView x:Name="tree" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=(local:Service.MonitoredProjects)}">
    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
            <EventSetter Event="Expanded" Handler="TreeViewItem_Expanded"/>
        </Style>
    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
</TreeView>
```

Спасибо неравнодушному товарищу за помощь!